# use Yourls bulk link shortener api and integrate it in form with javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, api

I want to integrate below api with my form, where user can input urls and on submit they should get result on same page just below input.
And result should be one url per line or in table rows.

These are official Instruction for api use

> Add in your api request the parameter **action=bulkshortener**
>       Send the list of the URLs to be shortened using the parameter **urls[]**.
>       The response contains each shortened URL in a single line.

### Example

Request API:

```
http://example.com/yourls-api.php?signature=ursecretkey&action=bulkshortener&urls[]=http://url1&urls[]=http://url2
```

*Result:* On result page it only shows shorten links in single line separated by single space only. 
http://example.com/zy1071 http://example.com/ha52ql

Comment: your form have multiple input ??

Comment: yes, because i want to shorten multiple urls

Comment: check this [API Details](https://yourls.org/#API) for more information

Comment: you can used jquery ajax